# What are the values of Task Manager's update intervals, in seconds?

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-manager

It would be useful to know how many seconds or milliseconds are assigned to the **Update speed** in **Task Manager**. It could help me do some quick and dirty calculations. For example, I can use its **Network Details** window quickly figure out which live audio-stream source has the higher bitrate when this information is not given:[image: Network Details from Task Manager]

The **Update speed** labels are `High`, `Normal` and `Low`, but what are their seconds values?

Comment: I have timed it, but I wasn't able to search up the values on the web, and thougth it would be useful to get these numbers out there.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)#Update_interval

The update interval can be set to High (0.5 s), Normal (2 s), Low (4 s), or Paused.

If you are using something like Process Explorer (Sysinternals) you can get more granular with .5, 1,2,5,10 or paused (in seconds).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I wish it were referenced. Though that registry node is missing in Windows 10, I wonder if adding it will override the defaults. I may test it out when I have less windows open... If it works I'll be sure to ask "How can I adjust the update speed in Task Manager" and @notify you :)